# Serverside NodeJS - need client windows ID

Tags: node.js, reactjs, active-directory

(intranet application) I'm using ReactJS with NodeJS as a server side api for accessing various resources (such as user active directory profile). I need to integrate with Active Directory, without prompting the user for their credentials.

Using ActiveDirectory for Node (npm i activedirectory) I can query the AD using LDAP for a hard coded sAMAccountName using the code below.

```
ad.findUser(sAMAccountName, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    if (!user) console.log('User: ' + sAMAccountName + ' not found.');
    else {
      thisUser = user;
    }
  });
```

But what I cant figure out, is how to pick up the current user ID when they call the API.

These 2 examples give the 'Server' user id, rather then the client ID:

```
const user = process.env;
const user = require('os').userInfo().username;
```

In .net I would normally do this with

```
string NTID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

So is there a way in NodeJS, running on a server, to access the client user ID?

**---------UPDATE:-----------**

I've been trying to implement the solution below using passport-windowsauth but cant quite get it working. I have the web.config file configured like this:

```
<iisnode watchedFiles="*.js;node_modules\*;routes\*.js;views\*.jade" promoteServerVars="LOGON_USER,AUTH_USER" />
<security>
     <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
     </authentication>
</security>
```

Azure configuration is set to:

[image]

This is the function I call when I click a button to start the authentication:

```
activeDirectory = () => {
    let url = '';
    //Default to current user when in dev
    if (
      window.location.href.indexOf('localhost') > -1
    ) {
      url = 'http://localhost:5000/express-passport';
    } else {
      url = '/express-passport';
    }
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: url,
      withCredentials: true
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log("Done: ", response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("An error occurred - ", error);
      });
};
```

And this is the NodeJs server route code:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const WindowsStrategy = require("passport-windowsauth");

module.exports = app => {
  let thisUser = {};
  passport.use(
    new WindowsStrategy(
      {
        ldap: {
          url: "ldap://somethingldap.somewhere.com/CN=,DC=,DC=,DC=,DC=",
          base: "CN=,DC=,DC=,DC=,DC=",
          bindDN: "serviceAccountDetailsHere",
          bindCredentials: "masked"
        }
      },
      function(profile, done) {
        thisUser = profile;
        console.log("Profile:", profile);
      }
    )
  );
  app.get(
    "/express-passport",
    function(req, res, next) {
      passport.authenticate("WindowsAuthentication", function(
        error,
        user,
        info
      ) {
        // log everything to console
        console.log(error);
        console.log(user);
        console.log(info);

        if (error) {
          res.status(401).send(error);
        } else if (!user) {
          res.status(401).send(info);
        } else {
          next();
        }

        res.status(401).send(info);
      })(req, res);
    },

    // function to call once successfully authenticated
    function(req, res) {
      res.status(200).send("logged in!");
    }
  );
};
```

So now, when the page opens I click a button, expecting it to authenticate. A popup appears asking for my credentials, which I enter, but the popup just disappears and reappears continuously. I'm obviously doing something incorrect...

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi

Comment: Should have mentioned, I'm using mac OS for development

Comment: You mentioned you're using mac OS for dev'ving - what's the final server going to be deployed to?

Comment: Its an internal Azure setup, so its a windows machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution I ended up using for this. It's a combination of 2 packages -

> express-ntlm

and

> ActiveDirectory

ntlm is used to pick up the user credentials from the browser (some users may have to provide those credentials if prompted). Once ntlm has userID, I use that to query the active directory to get more details for the user. The reason for 2 modules is that ntlm only provides 3 fields - UserName, DomainName and Workstation. In my case, I needed email address, first name, last name etc.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ntlm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory

```
const ntlm = require('express-ntlm');
const ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');

module.exports = app => {
  const config = {
    url: 'ldap://something.somewhere.com',
    baseDN: 'CN=a,DC=b,DC=c',
    username: '',
    password: ''
  };

  app.use(
    //This is for getting the users MS ID only
    ntlm()
  );

  app.get(‘/apiName/’, (req, res) => {
    let sAMAccountName = req.ntlm.UserName;
    const ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
    var userDetails = {
      Email: '',
      FirstName: '',
      LastName: ''
    };
    ad.findUser(sAMAccountName, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
      }

      if (!user) console.log('User: ' + sAMAccountName + ' not found.');
      else {
        userDetails.Email = user.mail;
        userDetails.FirstName = user.firstName;
        userDetails.LastName = user.lastName;
      }
      res.json(userDetails);
      res.end();
    });
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your biggest problem will be getting this working on your MacOS dev machine in a way that can be seamlessly transferred to a Windows machine and work the same way.

The [node-sspi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi) package is probably easiest, but it's also Windows-only.

I think your best bet would be to use the [passport-windowsauth](https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth) module for [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org) and use it with LDAP, since you can make LDAP queries to AD from any OS.

On the server, put it behind IIS and follow their instructions under [Integrated Authentication](https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth#integrated-authentication-iis) to setup IIS with Windows Authentication to make it a seamless login for users.

On your MacOS dev machine, you can't do that of course. I think the best you can do for MacOS is that it *will* ask you for credentials. You will have to test this out. I'm not sure if it will do authentication challenge without IIS like it normally would with (I don't think it will). If not, you can create a separate login page by following their [Non-integrated authentication](https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth#non-integrated-authentication) instructions and you only use that on your dev machine.

In the actual call to `passport.use()`, the only difference between the two is `integrated: false`. So you may find you will have to set that differently for local dev vs. the server (hopefully you can have your code detect if you're on your dev machine and set it to false automatically).

So yes, you'll have different login behaviour between your dev machine and the server, but at least you should be able to promote your code as-is and have it work in both places.

Comment: That sounds like a plan thanks. I'll give it a day or 2 to see if any other answers come in before applying the bounty but in the mean time I'll try this implementation

Comment: I've tried this implementation, but it continuously prompts for my credentials. Updated question above, any help appreciated.

Comment: You are doing a lot of logging to the console. Do you see any output there?

Comment: Does any of that change if you disable `anonymousAuthentication`? (change Windows Authentication setting to "Require")

Comment: Now I just get `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`. Nothing in the log

Comment: That's progress at least. If you aren't getting a 401 that means the Windows Authentication worked - just something in NodeJS is choking. You'll probably have to put some more logging in there to figure out why. Did you get it working on your dev machine?

Comment: Nope cant get it working locally either. Any suggestions on how/where to do the logging to debug the `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.` message?

Comment: I finally got this working.... combination of express-ntlm and activeDirectory did the trick. I'll post a full answer for future reference

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as you mentioned above `But what I can't figure out, is how to pick up the current user ID when they call the API.`

It seems the above code is wrapped under function which is used as route handler callback fn. by saying this I mean you will definitely have access to `req` and `res` aka `request` and `response` API function argument.

for example:-

```
module.exports = {
  routeHanlder: function(req, res) {
      ad.findUser(sAMAccountName, function(err, user) {
         if (err) {
           console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
         }

         if (!user) console.log('User: ' + sAMAccountName + ' not found.');
         else {
          thisUser = user;
         }
      });
  }
}
```

so in above example, the `req` argument contains all the client information which you want like from where the request comes, what are the request headers and so on.

as you mentioned in your question that `string NTID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;` by using `HttpContext` you can get user identity. By using `req` you will get client information.